# Picking $r$ balls from $k$ types of balls where $k-1$ types of balls have infinite supply and the $k^\text{th}$ type has only $1$ copy.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, alternative-proof

The question is as follows:

We need to pick $r$ balls. The sports shop has k types of balls, with an infinite number of each type of ball $c_1, c_2,\dots, c_{k−1}$ but only $1$ copy of $c_k$. In how many ways can you pick these $r$ balls?

My solution:

There are $2$ possibilities: $C_k$ is chosen or it is not.
if chosen then there are still $k$ options for the other $r-1$ balls left to be selected $= (r-1)^k$

if it is not chosen then there are $k-1$ options for each of the $r$ balls to be 
selected $= r^{k-1}$

Therefore the total number of ways to select the balls $= (r-1)^k + r^{k-1}$

I am not sure if my solution is correct. Alternate proof methods are also welcome.

Comment: You are correct to note that either $c_k$ is chosen or it is not and to partition your answer based on this.  The rest of the numbers you mention however, $(r-1)^k$ etc... are all incorrect.

Comment: Before continuing, we must first ask the question, "Do you care in what order the balls are selected?"  If you do care, then you will need to decide *where* within the sequence the ball of type $c_k$ occurred, and then for each other position, you choose what type of ball it is.  You have $r$ positions that the $c_k$ ball could occur in, and then for each other position, you have $k-1$ options for what type of ball it is, giving $r\times (k-1)\times (k-1)\times (k-1)\times \cdots \times (k-1) = r\cdot (k-1)^{r-1}$.  Note, the base is the number of options, the exponent is number of occurrences

Comment: If you do *not* care in what order the balls are selected, you will be using the technique of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Order of selection does not matter. Okay, so for the case where I don't select ck, I would have r stars (balls) and k different bars (types of balls) placed in the gaps. In the case where i select ck, how do i deal with the sigularity of ck? how do i make sure that the bar for ball type ck traps only 1 star (hence indicating only 1 of ck has been selected)?

Comment: If you don't select $c_k$ then you can completely ignore its existence and you will have $r$ stars and $k-2$ bars (*you use one fewer bar than the number of options, which with the removal of $c_k$ as an option leaves $k-1$ options so $k-2$ bars*).  If you do use $c_k$ then  you send one ball it's way and then from that point ignore it's existence, leaving $r-1$ remaining balls and again $k-2$ bars, giving a total of $\binom{r+k-2}{k-2}+\binom{r-1+k-2}{k-2}$ which can be simplified further if you desire via hockeystick identity.